# Find the name of the class that eventually does work in a string of method calls

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have a problem I need to solve and it revolves around the idea of code like the following.

```
public class x {
    private y yInstance;

    public bool doSomething() {
        return y.doSomething();
    }
}

public class y {
    private z zInstance;

    public bool doSomething() {
        return z.doSomething();
    }
}

public class z {
    public bool doSomething() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would like to, having an instance of x, be able to find out the class which actually does the work, in this case it is "z". However, in my case there can be any number of layers and more than one path could lead to the final class. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Note: I need to do this without actually calling the method.

Is this possible?

EDIT: This is very poor pseudo-code to demonstrate my use-case a little better as suggested. Note that in my repository I am using NHibernate criteria.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByCriteria(DetachedCriteria criterion) {
    if (criterion.Type.getFilterBase() == a)
        criterion.AppendFilter_a();

    if (criterion.Type.getFilterBase() == b)
        criterion.AppendFilter_b();

    if (criterion.Type.getFilterBase() == c)
        criterion.AppendFilter_c();

    return criterion.execute();
}
```

This is the idea. Note that in my case there are only 4 possible bases.

Comment: You could inspect the IL bytecode if you really have to... But there's likely a better approach for your actual problem. Why does that higher layer need to know a low-level class name? That's an implementation detail it should probably not concern itself with (nevermind that it could change, or that there may be multiple 'final classes' - and how do you determine which class is doing 'actual work'?).

Comment: That is definitely not an option. The reason is that depending on the underlying object we need to append a certain filter to all database calls for that object in our base repository.

Comment: And the lower layer can't take care of that filtering? Perhaps you should update your example code with something that actually reflects your use-case, to give us some more context.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I have updated the question

Comment: For your new example, I'd just create a virtual or abstract `AppendFilter` method in `DetachedCriteria` that each criteria subclass can implement in its own way.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually called the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

You could implement kind of a recursive function:

```
public class x {
    private y yInstance;
    public bool doSomething(){
        return y.doSomething();
    }
    public Type getWorkerClassType(){
        return yInstance.getWorkerClassType();
    }
}

public class y {
    private z zInstance;
    public bool doSomething(){
        return z.doSomething();
    }
    public Type getWorkerClassType(){
        return zInstance.GetType();
    }
}

public class z {
    public bool doSomething(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work, unfortunately I would need to update 150+ classes and I would like to avoid that...

Comment: You could use reflection to see if the instance in your current class has an instance itself and go all the way back to your original one (in this case `class z`). But depending on how much wrapper classes you have, this could take some time.

Comment: I spoke to my co-worker and it looks like your answer might be my eventual solution. I don't want to accept your answer just yet but I will if that is what I go with.